# Implementation of polar RZ line coding

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications, telecommunications

I am teaching a course in digital communication and I want to show students how different line coding schemes are implemented in Hardware. For codes like NRZ-L, NRZ-I, manchester, I found circuits based on comparator, logic gate and flip-flops, but for polar RZ, I didn't find anything (may be I didn't search well). So I tried to come up with a circuit myself which is shown below:
[image]

The output generates Polar RZ code according to simulation.
My question is: Are there any better and simple circuits to implement **Polar RZ** code?

Comment: It works hence it is correct.

Comment: Then compare Bi-Phase-M,S and I to show what advantages each has , worst case data pattern and spectral differences and why clock jitter degrades BER in noisy environments so better clock recovery schemes help. Then show HDD MFM, RLL etc